# Ubuntu 12.04 fails to boot after sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: 12.04, boot, upgrade, ati, fglrx

Yesterday I upgraded my system with `sudo apt-get upgrade`. I upgrade on a regular basis so not a lot of packages were installed and i don't know which ones this time.  But after that i booted my computer and he hangs on "Checking battery state".

I googled a bit and i could manage to start Unity, how:

```
crtl+alt+f1 to open a terminal
startx (this starts the graphical stuff)
once that was started i opened a terminal with ctrl+alt+T
and then the command: unity &disown
```

Now everything works as normal. But this is annoying, and how can this be fixed. After googling a while i guess that it has something to with my video card.

The info:

```
~$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6400M Series
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11631 Compatibility Profile Context
```

My video card: Radeon 6470M

I also tried to download the driver from http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run and followed these instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI but my system still hangs at boottime.

What do i need to do to get my system boot as normal again. If you need additional info let me know.

**Edit**: somehow Ubuntu can't work anymore with the proprietary drivers from Ati for Radeon HD 6400M Series. I reinstalled Ubuntu and everything works fine (at first sight), but i want to install the proprietary drives. Now the problem is that i can't connect a second screen to my laptop anymore ... therefore i need the proprietary driver

Comment: I had never seen `&disown` before. Excellent. To fix this completely I think you will have to figure out what is going wrong. Two things occur to me, either `compiz` isn't set up properly to start `unity` or there is a timing issue. ~/.xsession-errors or /var/log/syslog or /var/log/Xorg.0.log may have some hints in any case. You might also try logging into ubuntu-2d or onto unity with a different user-id to help narrow down what is happening or use radeon rather than fglrx. Does ~/.gconf/apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/%gconf.xml contain  a string "unityshell" and "unitymtgrabhandles"?

Answer (score 2):

After a few days I did a `sudo apt-get upgrade` again and I was able to install the proprietary driver again. Now everything works correctly again.

Comment: Cool--it seems the problem may have been fixed with an update (after having been introduced by an earlier update).

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps (I've done the steps now, so I don't know if they work):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Type `cd ~` (if you opened a folder before)
3. Type `nano .bash_profile`
4. Add to the file `unity &disown`
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, now press <kbd>Y</kbd>.
6. Reboot your computer typing `sudo reboot` and typing your password.

Comment: With this answer I believe you will still have to sign on to vt1 with Ctrl+Alt+F1 to run `startx`, but this will save you some typing.

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't solve the issue, this ensures that Unity gets started after logon.

Comment: Then I have no idea :/

Comment: Even for reinstall the drivers, I have no idea.